# Conversion from QString* to QString&

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, implicit, qstring

I'm confused about using pointers and references and I'm facing a little problem.

I got a function :

```
bool myObject::isFlag( QString &pArgument) const { }
```

And I'm using it with :

```
QStringList::const_iterator myQStringList.begin();

[...] && !isFlag( QString( *(myVar + 1)))
```

I got an error for the

```
QString( *(myVar + 1)))
```

which specifies taht no matching function is found.

However I'm pretty sure this should be good ... do you happen to know what could be the problem ?

Comment: Try not to create a temporary object, but create `QString( *(myVar + 1))` before your expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this call

```
isFlag( QString( *(myVar + 1)))
```

the argument is a temporary `QString`. You cannot bind non-const references to temporaries, you you would need to change `isFlag` to take a const reference:

```
bool myObject::isFlag( const QString &pArgument) const {
```

If you cannot use a `const` reference, then you should create a `QString`, then pass it to the function:

```
QString qs( *(myVar + 1));
isFlag(qs);
```

All of the above assumes that a `QString` can be constructed from, `*(myvar +1)`, which is, again, a temporary.